# Javascript to enter only positive or negative decimal number with 3 decimal places into a ASP.NET TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, textbox

I have one TextBox in my UserControl. Here I want enter only positive or negative decimal number with three decimal places.
For example like below:
        128.324, -23.453, 10, 0.453, -2, 2.34, -5.34
The TextBox should not allow to enter other characters. How to do this using JavaScript? I am not good enough in JavaScript.

Comment: You should only validate the content of form controls after the user has finished with them. Messing with the interface while they are typing is really annoying and can be really frustrated. Just let them know what the required format is and let them achieve it however they want. The content only needs to be valid when it is used, usually not until the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you validate on change your should be alright. Make sure you also validate any data that is sent to the server, on the server, since any data can be sent no matter how you try to validate it with JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById('tehinput');
input.onchange = function(){
    var val = this.value, sign = '';
    if(val.lastIndexOf('-', 0) === 0){
        sign = '-';
        val = val.substring(1);
    }
    var parts = val.split('.').slice(0,2);
        if(parts[0] && parseInt(parts[0], 10).toString() !== parts[0]){
        parts[0] = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        if(!parts[0])
            parts[0] = 0;
    }
    var result = parts[0];
    if(parts.length > 1){
        result += '.';
        if(parts[1].length > 3 || 
          parseInt(parts[1], 10).toString() !== parts[1]){
              parts[1] = parseInt(parts[1].substring(0,3), 10);
              if(!parts[1])
                  parts[1] = 0;
        }
        result += parts[1];
    }
    this.value = sign+result;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/8JQmX/)

Comment: I liked your demo but I am getting an error on my page... Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "onchange", input is null

Comment: I fixed that error by moving the JS to load after the input field. Now works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression to check content would be something like:

```
var re = /^[+-]?[\d,]+(\.\d{3})?$/;
```

but that will not enforce a comma for thousands, only allow it somewhere in the integer part. Note that in some countries, a comma is used for the decimal point.